# Android simulator - OkHttp (or Retrofit) callback not called

Tags: android, okhttp, simulator

I'm creating an Android app. When using the simulator (Android v10) the callback of my OkHttp Get request is not called. (Same with Retrofit).

When I test on the real device it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
        val url = "https://my.url/somewhere"

        var client =  OkHttpClient()

        var request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue( object: Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                showErrorDialog()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                debug("Got response")
                moveToMainView(Gson().fromJson(response.body?.string(), Model.Data::class.java))
            }
        })
```

Any ideas why it would not work on the Simulator?

Comment: Do both devices are on the same network?

Comment: @aiqency Yes. Both on the same network. I would expect it to go to the onFailure method if the simulator did not have network

Comment: You right but just in case I wanted to be sure. Did you see any error log about the ssl certificate maybe?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the request is being made when running in the simulator?